# Why does c++ calls the parent default constructor implicitly?

Tags: c++, constructor

As far as I know, Constructors are not inherited, but when I tried out this code it throws an error about not having no appropriate default constructor

```
// Element.h
enum orientation{ up, down, left, right };

 class Element{
public:
    float get_value()  ;
    string get_unit();
    Point get_start_point();
protected:
    //Element(); // To prevent instatiation
    float value;
    const string unit;
    Point starting_point;
    orientation direction;

 };

class Resistance : public Element{
public:
    Resistance(Point,float,orientation);
private :
    const string unit = "Kohm";
};
```

From this error, I got that the parent class constructor is called implicitly.
Note that error disappears when I declare constructor for Element.

```
//Element.cpp
float Element::get_value(){
return value;
};
string Element::get_unit(){
    return unit;
}
Point Element::get_start_point()
{
    return starting_point;
}
Resistance::Resistance(Point p, float value, orientation direction){

    Resistance::starting_point = p;
    Resistance::value = value;
    Resistance::direction = direction;
}
```

What's the thing that I am missing here ?
Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/vXyRSl. Perhaps the problem is that `Point` (which you haven't shown us) doesn't have an accessible default constructor, which would inhibit the generation of one for `Element`, and hence for `Resistance`. Perhaps you could post the exact error, and enough code to reproduce it?

Comment: Point have accessible default constructor. 
The problem will rise when u try to implement Constructors for child classes

Comment: Then please post enough code to reproduce the error. As I said, the code you've posted compiles without error, making it hard to guess what your problem is.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorry, my fault.

Comment: The updated code also compiles without error: http://ideone.com/vXyRSl. Perhaps your real `Element` class also declares a non-default constructor, which inhibits the generation of a default one? In that case, you'll need to provide constructor arguments in the derived class's initialiser list.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't know why, but I found it's something related to const .. which I can't understand .Anyway I gave up especially after the Down ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way how OO works. In your example, because of inheritance, you declare that Resistance is also an Element, only a special kind of it.

It makes no sense to construct a child class without constructing the base; it would leave base in an inconsistent (or rather uninitialized) state.

Declare `Element()` as protected, to avoid instantiation of the base class, just as you did it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your question:

1. Each `Resistance` *contains* an `Element` subobject which needs to be constructed. After all, you can subsequently assign a `Resistance*` to an `Element*`. Just think about what this means for a second, and it should be clear that a constructor of `Element` must be called.
2. If you declare a default constructor in a class, you declare to the compiler that you are not satisfied with the default constructor that it would normally generate. So, you need to actually supply an implementation for it.